# Shader ColorMask and ScrollView Mask Causing material to not update

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

I've got the following shader, based on a shader I created a number of years ago to handle progress bar type objects, similar to Alpha Cutoff, but with a few changes.

One of these changes is the series of `[HideInInspector]` properties that allow the shader to function properly on UI `Images`. However, the `ColorMask` property (which is partly responsible for ScrollRect views clipping objects outside of the masked area) causes the material to not update correctly when its values are changed.

[image: Example behavior]

1. The graphic not updating, masked by the ScrollRect
2. The graphic updating, not masked

If the `_ColorMask` property (and `ColorMask[_ColorMask]`) is removed, this happens instead:

[image: Bad]

```
Shader "Unlit/AlphaCutoffAA_UI" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Color Multiplier", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1) // color
        _Cutoff ("Cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Blend ("Blend Range", Range(0,.2)) = 0.1

        [HideInInspector]_StencilComp("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
        [HideInInspector]_Stencil("Stencil ID", Float) = 1
        [HideInInspector]_StencilOp("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
        [HideInInspector]_StencilWriteMask("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        [HideInInspector]_StencilReadMask("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255
        [HideInInspector]_ColorMask("Color Mask", Float) = 15  //adding this breaks everything
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="TransparentCutout"}
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        LOD 100

        Lighting Off

        Stencil
        {
            Ref[_Stencil]
            Comp[_StencilComp]
            Pass[_StencilOp]
            ReadMask[_StencilReadMask]
            WriteMask[_StencilWriteMask]
        }
        ColorMask[_ColorMask]

        Pass {  
            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata_t {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                fixed _Cutoff;
                fixed _Blend;
                float4 _Color;

                v2f vert (appdata_t v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                    o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
                {
                    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                    if(col.a < _Cutoff) {
                        col.a = 0;
                    }
                    else if (col.a == 1) {
                        col.a = 1.0;
                    }
                    else if(col.a < _Cutoff + _Blend) {
                        col.a = (col.a - _Cutoff + (_Blend/100)) / _Blend;
                    }
                    else {
                        col.a = 1.0;
                    }
                    col.r *= _Color.r;
                    col.g *= _Color.g;
                    col.b *= _Color.b;
                    col.a *= _Color.a;
                    return col;
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would also like a proper answer to this problem.
A workaround I've found is to disable and re-enable the Image/RawImage after changing material properties.
eg

```
Image.material.SetColor("_blah", color);
Image.enabled = false;
Image.enabled = true;
```